# Facebook Open Graph Action Submission for Review

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

I'm using Woobox Sweepstakes for my facebook page promotions. There is an option to have custom app, so when app is asking for permissions, user can see my brand instead of Woobox default app (see image - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2547869/app.jpg)

Next step would be to create open graph actions, so actions are posted to users timeline.

The problem is, when I submit open graph actions, facebook gives me an error - "You must provide a page with your Page Tab app installed"

However there is a tab installed on my page (see image - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2547869/facebook_error.PNG)

How do I submit my open graph actions for an approval?

Comment: Same error for me: I've sent a bug report to Developers Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/246011832239380/

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug as @olegueret told. 
Its resolved now. Try submitting the app again.